# using kgdb on kernel 3.18

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kgdb

I am using 64 bit ARMV8, on Kernel 3.18 based android device.

I am trying to use kgdb using kgdboc on Serial port. When I try to enable the kgdboc, it gets failed (Error -19).

> echo ttyS1 > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: May be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155577/how-to-use-kgdb-on-arm